# linux + how to match UUID in fstab file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, perl

I need to wrote the follwing task that will be part in my bash script

we want to match all lines with **UUID** words in fstab file according to the following rules:

UUID is in begging of file or beginning after space or spaces or tab

example

```
UUID="61e9e16f-eb49-4c97-aaf0-0ed2dc3f3007"
      UUID="61e9e16f-eb49-4c97-aaf0-0ed2dc3f3007"
    UUID="61e9e16f-eb49-4c97-aaf0-0ed2dc3f3007"
```

second it will not match on the following cases

if UUID is begin after comment "#" or UUID isnt in the beging of file

example

```
#UUID="61e9e16f-eb49-4c97-aaf0-0ed2dc3f3007"
 "61e9e16f-eb49-4c97-aaf0-0ed2dc3f3007" UUID
#      UUID="61e9e16f-eb49-4c97-aaf0-0ed2dc3f3007"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple **`grep`** approach:

```
grep '^[[:space:]]*UUID=' file
```

- `[:space:]` - space characters: in the `C` locale, this is tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space

Comment: is it support also TAB spaces?

Comment: @yael, mostly - yes, you may extend character class to `[[:space:][:blank:]]*`